Why was Bhisma unable to glorify Lord Shiva as he previously glorified Sri Hari Vishnu without hesitation?
In Mahabharata, Anushasana Parva we see that when Yudhisthira asked Bhishma to say about Lord Shiva , Bhisma expressed his inability to do so but when Yudhisthira asked to glorify Vishnu ji then Bhisma didn't hesitateto glorify Shri Hari Vishnu. Bhisma said he can't glorify Lord Shiva only Krishna can... and even Krishna said Noone even he himself don't know him fully.. Krishna said he will try to glorify...
Why ?
Why Lord Shiva can't be glorified

Unpopular take - The Mahabharata has several interpolations, and this is especially true for the Shanti parva and Anushasana parva.

Iskconite ? Lol ...As always some Hilarious Shiva haters(manly some vaishnavas)..... who can't accept Shiva's glory... just say Shiva's glory is Interpolation,  Tamasic etc etc and ran away...

@estimator bogus take

It does seem to be an unpopular take. :)

Just to clarify - I did not downvote your question.

@estimator you can down vote if you wish... not a problem

Lord Shiva is beyond words, beyond description, beyond Stutis, beyond thoughts, beyond imaginations, He is Anadi Ananta. He is both Sagun Sakara, Nirgun Nirakara and again he is beyond all too -


On that chapter Bhisma and Shri Krishna themselves answered this
question

"Bhishma said :  'I am quite incompetent to recite the virtues of
Mahadeva of highest intelligence. He pervades all things in the
universe and yet is not seen anywhere. He is the creator of universal
self and the Pragna (knowing) self and he is their master. All the
deities, from Brahman to the Pisacas, adore and worship him. He
transcends both Prakriti and Purusha. It is of Him that Rishis,
conversant with Yoga and possessing a knowledge of the tattvas, think
and reflect. He is indestructible and Supreme Brahman. He is both
existent and non-existent. Agitating both Prakriti and Purusha by
means of His energy, He created therefrom the universal lord of
creatures, viz., Brahma. Who is there that is competent to tell the
virtues of that god of gods, that is endued with supreme Intelligence?
Man is subject to conception (in the mother’s womb), birth,
decrepitude, and death. Being such, what man like me is competent to
understand Bhava?
~ Mahābhārata, Anuśāsana Parva,  14.3-7

"Vasudeva said :  'The very deities with Indra, and the Grandsire
Brahma numbering among them, and the great Rishis also, are
incompetent to understand the course of Mahadeva’s acts truly and in
all their details. Even He is the end which all righteous people
attain. The very Adityas who are endued with subtile sight, are unable
to behold his abode. How then can one that is merely a man succeed in
comprehending Him?[4] I shall, therefore, truly recite to you some of
the attributes of that illustrious slayer of Asuras, who is regarded
as the Lord of all sacrifices and vows.
~ Mahābhārata,  AnuśāsanaParva, 14.22-23


Pushpadant ji in his Shiva Mahimṇa Stotram said

असित-गिरि-समं स्यात् कज्जलं सिन्धु-पात्रे सुर-तरुवर-शाखा लेखनी
पत्रमुर्वी । लिखति यदि गृहीत्वा शारदा सर्वकालं तदपि तव गुणानामीश पारं
न याति ॥
~ Śrī Śiva Mahimṇa Stotram, 32
"O Shiva, if ink is prepared by mixing the blue mountain with the sea,
the branches of the tree of the Garden of the Gods are made stylus,
and the earth is used as paper and Bhagwati Sharda Devi i.e. Saraswati
Devi continues to write till eternity, O Lord! It will not be possible
to fully explain your qualities.


           ॥ सर्वं शिवमयं जगत् ॥ 

Entire Universe is wholly Lord Shiva, Each and everything is Shiva Only.

Bhishma's view of Bhagawan Mahadeva.:
MBH 13:14:183.:

“Thou (Mahādeva) art he that hadst created from thy right side the Grandsire Brahma, the Creator of all things. Thou art he that hadst created from thy left side Vishnu for protecting the Creation. Thou art that puissant Lord who didst create Rudra (the destroyer deity Kalagni-Rudra) when the end of the Yuga came and when the Creation was once more to be dissolved”.

MBH 13:14:9.:

“That Vishnu who knows every thing, who has greatest qualities, who cannot be won over by anybody, who has special holy sight, and who is greatly resplendent, always sees and remains connected (viz meditate on) him (Rudra) by his eyes of yoga”.

MBH 13:14:10-11.:

"The Krishna, due to his devotion to Supreme Lord Rudra, Has spread all over the universe, Oh Bharatha, Oh king of kings, After making Lord Shiva pleased by his penance in Bhadrinath, He has attained the state of being more dear, Than all the worlds and all aspects of knowledge."

MBH 13:14:13.:

“In every new Yuga has Krishna (by such penances) gratified Mahadeva. In every Yuga has Mahadeva been gratified with the great devotion of the high-souled Krishna“.

Even after knowing so much why he could not glorify Bhagawan Mahadeva.?
It's because no one not even Lord Brahma, Lord Vishnu, Lord Indra, etc are incapable of knowing the glories of Bhagawan Shiva.:
SB 8:7:31.:

O Lord Girîsha, since the You are Brahman which is transcendental to the material modes of goodness, passion and ignorance, the various directors of this material world certainly cannot appreciate it or even know where it is. It is not understandable even to Lord Brahmâ, Lord Vishnu or the King of heaven, Mahendra.

Sri Shivananda Lahari by Jagat Guru Sri Adi Shankaracharya Ji Maharaja.:


Oh Consort of Uma,
Oh Lord who is everywhere,
Heaps of material for thine worship is ready,
But how will I ever worship thee?
Neither I can become a swan nor a boar,
And how will I ever find your crown and your tender feet,
When even Brahma and Vishnu who took those forms ,
Could not ever know about them.


Even Vedas knows only a single part of him.:
Rig Veda 10:90:4.:

“Three quarters of his are beyond all this; all of this creation is but from one quarter of him. Again and again, all that eats, and that eats not appeared from this one quarter of His.”

Atharvana veda 10:7:9.:

"How far within the past hath Skambha (Linga/pillar) entered? How much of him hath reached into the future? That one part which he set in thousand places,—how far did Skambha (linga/pillar) penetrate within it?"

Atharva Veda 10:7:25.:

"Great, verily, are those Gods who sprang from non-existence into life. Further, men say that that one part of Skambha (linga or pillar) is nonentity".

Atharva Veda 10:7:26.:

“Where Skambha (Agni-Linga) generating gave the Ancient World its shape and form, They recognized that single part of Skambha (Linga) as the Ancient World.”

Atharvaveda 10:8.13.:

“He with one half engendered all Creation (bhuvanam). What sign is there to tell us of the other?”

Ekakshara Upanishad 1-3.:

“Thou art the one Imperishable in the Imperishable, conjoint with Uma. As known by means of Susumna, here (on the empirical plane), the one firm (Principle art Thou). Thou art the ancient source of the world, the Lord of beings; Thou the Parjanya (the Principle of lifegiving water), the Protector of the world. Thou art the Principle of life; Thou the manifestation (the manifested world); Thou the source of the world; by a quarter hast Thou pervaded this world. Thou art the world’s birth, the cause, the life supreme, and the child in the womb armed with the excellent bow and arrow”.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..
